# What is wrong with my function? (new to user defined functions)

Tags: php, function, forms, post

I am trying to post from a previous page with a form on it, and rather then typing out the code over and over again i tried making a function for it, it didnt work. thanks in advance

```
function postORempty($field){
isset($_POST[$field]) ? $_POST[$field] : "";
}

$szFname= postORempty('fname');
```

Answer (score 2):

You do not return any value. Try to add the return keyword.

```
function postORempty($field)
{
    return (isset($_POST[$field]) ? $_POST[$field] : "");
}

$szFname= postORempty('fname');
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't return it...

```
function postORempty($field){ 
return isset($_POST[$field]) ? $_POST[$field] : ""; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function is not returning a value.

```
function postORempty($field){ return isset($_POST[$field]) ? $_POST[$field] : "";}
```

That said, if $_POST['fname'] does exist then PHP gives null, which is equal to an empty string anyway.

Comment: If the index doesn't exist then an `E_NOTICE` is given, since you are trying to access an undefined index. Since the default error reporting level is `E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE` it won't show up unless you tell it to, but if you care about `E_NOTICE`s, the function has a point.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't returned any value

```
function postORempty($field){ 
      return isset($_POST[$field]) ? $_POST[$field] : ""; 
}
$szFname= postORempty('fname');
```

Answer (score 0):

It has a if check but doesnt know what to do with the result. I presume you want it to be echoed so this is what it should be:

```
function postORempty($field)
{ 
echo ((isset($_POST[$field])) ? $_POST[$field] : ""); 
}
```

or return it:

```
function postORempty($field)
{ 
return ((isset($_POST[$field])) ? $_POST[$field] : ""); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you forget the return and empty() is better